# how to convert a column with dates(string) to a date only in pyspark

Tags: sql, dataframe, date, pyspark, databricks

i have  a dataframe with a "created_at" column that contains dates that look like this:

```
Mon Jan 27 17:16:46 +0000 2020
```

and i want to convert this column dates to:

```
2020-01-27
```

how can i do this in pyspark?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Jave SimpleDate Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details regarding datetime characters.

```
df.show(truncate=False) #sample dataframe

#+------------------------------+
#|created_at                    |
#+------------------------------+
#|Mon Jan 27 17:16:46 +0000 2020|
#+------------------------------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("created_at", F.to_date("created_at","EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss +SSSS yyyy")).show()

#+----------+
#|created_at|
#+----------+
#|2020-01-27|
#+----------+
```